# JS Async call freezes css3 animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous

I'm creating a webapp that calls our API through AJAX.

I'm not using any framework.

Here is my indeterminate `progress` HTML (just a copy from firefox building blocks)

```
<progress class="pack-activity light" value="0" max="100" data-status="off">
</progress>
```

Here is my CSS that triggers the progress

```
progress[data-status="off"] {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
       -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
            transition: opacity 1s;
}

progress[data-status="on"] {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
            transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

Here is the progress animation

```
progress[value].pack-activity {
    background-image: url("../img/activity.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    animation: 0.5s move infinite steps(15);
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to   { background-position: .64rem 0; }
}
```

This works well if I turn `data-status` on **without** doing an AJAX call.

When I do it, the animation 'freezes' until the AJAX call finishes. (I only could trigger the progress bar doing a `setTimeout` on the request)

```
window.setTimeout(function()
{
inevent.personController.signIn(email.value, password.value, function(data, exception)
{
    progress.setAttribute('data-status', 'off');

    if(exception !== undefined)
    {
        transition.message.setAttribute('data-status', 'on');

        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            transition.message.setAttribute('data-status', 'off');
        }, 3000);

        switch(exception.content.status)
        {
            case 409:
                transition.message.innerHTML = "Please fill all fields!";
                break;
            case 401:
                transition.message.innerHTML = "Username or password incorrect!";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        transition.next('home');
    }
});
}, 200);

progress.setAttribute('data-status', 'on');
```

AJAX CALL

```
execHttp : function() {
    try 
    {
        return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
    } 
    catch(e1)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
        }
        catch(e2)
        {
            return new XMLHttpRequest()
        }
    }
},

send : function(url, callback, method, from, data, sync) {

    var exec = this.execHttp();

    if(this.parent.config.sandbox)
    {
        url += "&sandbox=1";
    }

    exec.open(method, url, sync);

    var api = this;

    exec.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(exec.readyState == 4)
        {
            var returnData = null;

            if(exec.responseText != "" && exec.responseText != null)
            {
                returnData = JSON.parse(exec.responseText);
            }

            if(callback[1] != null && callback[1] !== undefined)
            {
                try
                {
                    callback[1](returnData, exec, from, callback[0]);
                }
                catch (exception)
                {
                    console.log(exception);

                    if(api.checkCallback(callback[0]))
                    {
                        callback[0](null, exception);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw from.exception.simple("A callback is required.", "Api.send");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(callback[1] != null && callback[1] !== undefined)
            {
                try
                {
                    callback[1](returnData, exec, from, callback[0]);
                }
                catch (exception)
                {
                    console.log(exception);

                    if(api.checkCallback(callback[0]))
                    {
                        callback[0](null, exception);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw from.exception.simple("A callback is required.", "Api.send");
            }
        }
    }

    if(method == 'POST')
    {
        exec.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }
    else
    {
        exec.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
    }

    exec.send(data);

},
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://mauriciogiordano.com:3000/webapp/webapp/

**SOURCE CODE:** https://github.com/estudiotrilha/InEvent/tree/webapp-dev

I don't know if it is possible to solve this, but I wondering if is there an explanation about it.

Thanks!

Comment: What does that "ASYNCCALL" function look like?

Comment: The code is really huge... I have a signIn function that access an API controller that, inside, has an AJAX request sender
Everything is on github. See the edit.

Comment: Can't find `AYSNCCALL()` on your github or in the page you've linked.  Can you make this less of a hide and seek game and just point us to the actual code for that function?

Comment: See the edit... but doesn't matter what the function does, all we need to know is that it uses XMLHttpRequest

Comment: inevent.personController.signIn() please look at line 45 in controllers/person.controller.js

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano - uhhh, if your browser is freezing during the ajax call, then it absolutely matters what the ajax call does.  Probably you are doing a synchronous ajax call instead of asynchronous or some code something is looping.  The point is that the problem is caused in the ajax code and you won't share that.

Comment: In the signIn function, you call `this.api.get()` and you pass it only three arguments, leaving off the fourth argument which is the `sync` option.  I'd suggest you set that specifically to `true` so it will be async for sure.  It might still be defaulting to async, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: but why a sync call freezes a css3 animation?

Comment: A sync call freezes all activity in the browser of any kind.  You can't even type chars into an input field or click on a button.  Synchronous AJAX calls are simply evil and should always be avoided.  Remember that CSS3 animations can trigger JS events, but those events couldn't run if in a sync ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since my comment worked, I will turn it into an answer:

In the `signIn()` function, you call `this.api.get()` and you pass it only three arguments, leaving off the fourth argument which is the sync option. I'd suggest you set that specifically to true so it will be async for sure. It might still be defaulting to async, but I can't tell for sure and explicitly passing the right options for async behavior will guarentee you get what you want.